# How do we improve the training effect of edit queues?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

This grew out of the comments at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191702/229547).  The basic concern is that the existing system is failing at training new users to edit posts.  Some concerns include

1. Users don't know why (or for the most part if) their edits were rejected.
2. Users may develop and retain bad habits to comply with the edit rules (in particular, the avoidance of tiny edits).
3. Reviewers may not always recognize bad edits.  (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted) for some discussion of that.)

Some suggestions that I made:

1. Add a "Didn't solve all the problems" reason for rejecting an edit, distinct from the "Too Minor" reason.
2. Display all the rejection reasons to the user somewhere (this exists under the "suggested edit" link on the page that lists all the suggested edits; not clear if it tells the editor what choice was picked; if it does, that should also be linked).
3. Change the page that displays the list of suggested edits to show if they were rejected, accepted, improved, rewritten, or rolled back (or still under review).  This has been suggested previously as "Issue 2" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history) and as "Feature 2" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor).
4. Allow users to view the text of rejected edits as well as successful ones.  (This already exists if you click the "suggested edit" link, as in #2.)
5. Allow users to improve their rejected edits (so long as subsequent edits haven't been made).

The goal here is to encourage users to improve their future edits.  Feedback helps with that.

Comment: [Why can't we just do this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) Please? Pretty please?

Comment: #2 & 3 are dups (Cody found that), #4 already exists as you see all of your suggest edits in the user profile.  If you mean something different, you might want to explain it in more detail.  I don't see a huge value in #5 most rejected edits aren't worth it.  However, I do like #1.  It already exists as the "too minor" reject reason, but similar phrasing could added that description of the "too minor" reason to it is clear.

Comment: @psubsee2003  No, for #4, not the list of edits, the edits themselves.  Currently, I can't see what the edit is or why it was rejected.  I can sort of determine that it was rejected if I look at the edit history, but that's difficult.  If we change the system to display why the edit was rejected, we should also show what was rejected.

Comment: @Brythan you mean you want the revision page of the question (for example, the [revision page of this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/191713/revisions)) to show rejected edits?  How would this work, show all rejected edits, or just your own rejected edits?

Comment: I also think that the "Didn't solve all the problems" reason is distinct from the "too minor" reason.  This is true for both reviewers and editors.  "Didn't solve all the problems" encourages editors to expand their edits to cover more problems.  "Too Minor" encourages reviewer shopping.  Another reviewer may pass an edit that a previous reviewer rejected.  It also encourages solving non-existent problems to make the edit not "Too Minor" anymore.

Comment: @psubsee2003  It should be possible somewhere (not necessarily the revision page) to see my own rejected edits with the rejection reason (or reasons if the reviewers disagree).  It should also be possible for a reviewer to see what edits have been rejected (from all editors) if they want.  It probably should not be possible for someone who can't make their own edits alone to see the rejected edits of others.  And of course these should be blocked from search engines.  I could live with this being on the revisions page, but I'm not sure that's the best interface (rather cluttered).

Comment: A better interface might be to link rejected edits to their own page and then link from there to the appropriate revision on the revision page (the base from which the edit was made).  That avoids clogging the revisions page.  Not sure about the reviewer view.  Perhaps they could switch the revisions page to show all (including rejected edits).  Not sure how they would be numbered though.

Comment: @Brythan I think you need to explain that feature in your post better then.  `Allow users to view rejected edits as well as successful ones.` does not fully explain what you are suggesting here.

Comment: @CodyGray  I'd love to see Feature#2 from your link.  Yes, please do that.